# standalone trigger to be raised everytime ANY sheet is opened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have searched on google and stack overflow, could not find an answer for this.

I am trying to create a trigger which will occur everytime ANY sheet is opened in my drive.

I have a lot of log files from field exported and saved as sheets and I would like to run script to check the obvious errors in the log and highlight them. I am able to run in as a simple onOpen() within the sheet. But this needs manual step of copying the code everytime I open a new log sheet.

Some articles indicate it is not possible, like this one
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112123/how-do-you-create-an-installable-trigger-for-a-google-apps-script

Is it possible? To create a standalone script not bound to any sheet and trigger it everytime a sheet is opened.

Another way I understand is create programmatically.

```
    function createOpenTrigger() {
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("runScript")
   .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
   .onOpen()
   .create();
}
```

But i am not sure when would this code be run and where do I put this code?

Could anyone please help

Comment: It's not possible unless you bind this function to  every single one of the spreadsheets on your Drive (which you can do programmatically though).

Comment: @ziganotschka how does one bind a function in a standalone project to all of the spreadsheets?

Comment: Well it wouldn't be a standalone project, but a bound one for each file - bulk-created with the Apps Script API.